# How to remove duplicates and originals in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**I have this:**

> +-------+-------+-------------+
>   | fname | lname |     DOB     |
>   +-------+-------+-------------+
>   | Anna  | Pass  | 1999-02-09  |
>   | Anna  | Pass  | 1999-02-09  |
>   | Ano   | Click | 1995-03-30  |
>   | Ano   | Click | 1995-03-30  |
>   | Chro  | Slip  | 1955-09-27  |
>   | Chro  | HONEY | 1955-09-27  |
>   +-------+-------+-------------+

**Desired result:**

> +-------+-------+-------------+
>   | fname | lname |     DOB     |
>   +-------+-------+-------------+
>   | Chro  | Slip  | 1955-09-27  |
>   | Chro  | HONEY | 1955-09-27  |

**My effort**:

After removing all duplicates, I got rid of duplicates in first 4 rows. but I cannot get rid of originals

Comment: I don't understand why your desired results wouldn't include one Anna Pass and one Ano Click.

Comment: you are right it should include but I want to get rid of duplicates as well as originals.I am changing the question header.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by create a key?

Comment: @gaten He gave you a sample formula for a key.  What about the formula do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [duplicate master addin](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1&id=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1!122)

*settings*

[image]

*output*

[image]

Comment: @ brettdj for the answer and it is great! I will use it as well, but for my learning I need to know why my formula is not working with reference to your first image I am applying =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$C$6,A1:C1)=0,0,1) but when it come to A5:C5 it is not changing to 1 this is the formula at A5:C5 =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$C$6,A5:C5)=0,0,1)